# Number of non-zero co-efficients in a series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $c_n \geq 0$ for all $n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nr^n$ converges for all $r\geq 1$, is it true that only finitely many $c_n$ are non-zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the series $e^r = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n!}r^n$. What is its radius of convergence?

Comment: Thanks for the nice counter example. The factorial grows faster than any exponential.